# HTML Flexbox Layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to change my layout from:

[image]

My codestructure looks like this:

```html
<body style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;">
 <div id="green" style="display: none;"></div>
 <div id="red"></div>
 <div id="blue" style="flex: 1;"></div>
</body>
```

to this:

[image]

My codestructure looks like this:

I can't figureout a nice way without moving the red one to the blue one and set the styling of the red one to the green one. So without changing the HTML, only the CSS.

Comment: As you commented at my answer (which I now have deleted), it is not clear in your question that the markup can't be altered. Please update accordingly.

Comment: May I ask why the markup can't be changed?

Comment: I already have a big html structure

Answer (score 0):

Because of your comment in my first answer

> the green div should have every time the full page height when the page is higher than the viewport, and if not, then just the viewport
>   height. So to answer your question, it (the blue div) should grow with
>   the content.

it is not possible to solve without a change in the markup (at least with `flex`).

---

Update

Other than `flex`, and to not alter the markup, I found only one way, which assume the green div never have content that exceed the viewport or the blue div, if it is higher than the viewport.

The trick I pulled here is to use a pseudo element on the blue div that fill up from bottom, making the green div appear to stretch all the way.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  border: 4px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#green {
  float: left;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-color: green;
  border-bottom: 0;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: calc(100% - 4px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 4px);
}
#red {
  float: right;
  border-color: red;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  height: 80px;
}
#blue {
  float: right;
  border-color: blue;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  min-height: calc(100% - 80px);
  position: relative;
}
#blue:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% + 4px);
  bottom: -4px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 4px solid green;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="green">
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
  Side bar<br>
</div>
<div id="red">
  Header
</div>
<div id="blue">
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
  Content<br>
</div>
```

Comment: any other suggestion with just css?

Comment: @Mr.Tr33 I will have a look later, drop you a message when done.

Answer (score 0):

**If your HTML structure is so big that it can't be changed, that's your first problem.** Fix that, *then* look into changing your CSS.

---

With that in mind, here's my answer:

With flexbox, it's hard to do what you want, how you want it done, without restructuring your HTML even a bit (like, a simple wrapper around `#red` and `#blue`). Thus... instead of using flexbox... I used... absolute positioning.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
div {
  border: 4px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
}
#green {
  border-color: green;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30%;
}
#red {
  border-color: red;
  height: 25%;
  width: 70%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#blue {
  border-color: blue;
  height: 75%;
  width: 70%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="green">Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content </div>
  <div id="red">Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content </div>
  <div id="blue">Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try to run the code and than scroll down a bit? If the content gets out of the viewport then the border is not growing.

Comment: @Mr.Tr33 I know. If you're not willing to restructure your HTML, but use this solution, you'll need to find a fix for that. Try `overflow: hidden`, or just make sure that your content is never that long.